# Retrieve Firebase analytics console data via rest api

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm new to Firebase analytics. I've implemented added firebase events on my app but now I want to share the Firebase analytics data with stake holders. Are there rest api's available to get analytics data? If yes, please provide me link for their guides. Or if no what is the other way to do the same ?

Thanks in advance